# Web application role management

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net and developing an application where there will be some roles like (admin, entry user, maker, checker) one user can have all or can have partial roles based on the provided roles and the page should restrict functionality based on the user role.

What is the best way of implementing it without memberships in asp.net ..

thanks

Answer (score 0):

How can define a role without membership?  You have to know who they are in order to get their role, otherwise there is no point.

Comment: well i have a user table and role table where i have some predefined roles. I have implemented a stored procedure which gets the role according to the user id and using formauthentication ticket .. is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: @user239684 - No, the right way of doing it is using the asp.net membership and role provider methods, because this hooks in with the general asp.net security methods.  If you absolutely need your own method of doing it, then create your own providers